# faster or batch alternative to python's socket.gethostbyaddr()?

Tags: python, networking, python-sockets, gethostbyaddr

Is there a faster or batch alternative to socket.gethostbyaddr() for the purpose of determining the host, given an IP address? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **dnspython** module [1], look from_address function.

Note: It's thread safe.

[1] http://www.dnspython.org/