# python3 - detect ip exists cost too much time

Tags: python-3.x

When run below code to detect if a interface with ip exist, it cost 4.5 secs on my windows machine!

```
import socket
import timeit

def ip_exist(host):
    try:
        socket.gethostbyaddr(host)
        return True
    except socket.herror:
        return False
        pass

start_time = timeit.default_timer()
retval = ip_exist("192.168.128.1")  
print(retval)
print(timeit.default_timer() - start_time)
```

I wish the solution work for both windows and linux. please help share right way to do it!

Comment: Have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17915094/faster-or-batch-alternative-to-pythons-socket-gethostbyaddr ?

Comment: I personally use `pythonping` package to check if interface is up, it has almost no delay, and the trick is to set  `timeout` so your interface doesnt spend too much time on that.